# XBox 360 connect to Notebook or HD monitor via hdmi

Tags: xbox-360

If I buy XBox 360 but I do not have television and I buy Xbox HDMI cable can I connect it to my notebook which has 1 HDMI stock?

Or I have to buy monitor with HDMI stock and use it as output device?

Also if I can conect it to my notebook what should I do to play on XBox live?

I do not buy anything yet, so I will thank for any good answer

Comment: What model notebook do you have? I would have thought that the HDMI port was output only.

Comment: hp probook 4525s

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would assume that the HDMI port on the laptop is output only - for connecting the laptop to an external monitor. I can't find anything on the HP web site that indicates otherwise. In that case connecting the XBox to the laptop will do nothing (I would hope that connecting two HDMI outputs wouldn't damage either one).

If that's the case then you will need to buy a monitor with HDMI or component inputs to play games - you'll also need audio output - so buying one with integral speakers might be the best approach.

Comment: I have a 22" 1080p monitor w/ HDMI, and a good pair of headphones for audio. The setup works great for me.

Answer (score 0):

Also look at the possibilities offered here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/34544/how-do-i-use-my-laptop-as-a-screen-for-ps3
I'm currently thikink obout the external TV tuner, but concerning the output quality...